# Test observable catch method

Tags: angular, unit-testing, observable

I have a component invoke service which typically return observable .

```
let res = this.serviceApi.getInfo();

res.subscribe(()=>do smothing;)

res.catch(()=>{

do smoething;
return Observable.throw('error)
});
```

i would like how to test res.catch? 
i tired to mock the serivce and return Observable.throw('error') but the test throw error

Comment: Be aware that `catch` is an operator and, as such, it returns an observable which has to be subscribed to for the `catch` to be composed into the chain. You are calling `catch` and are ignoring the returned observable - so the call to `catch` will be ineffectual.

Answer (score 1):

There is 2 problems with your code

1 - as cartant pointed out, you are calling .catch() on your observable sequence instead of adding it to your observable sequence. you can add it by reassigning res

```
res = res.catch(err => {
    return Observable.throw('error');
});
```

however I think it is better practice to define the observable sequence when you initialize it. This keeps the observable definition in one place

```
let res = this.serviceApi.getInfo()
    .catch(err => {
        return Observable.throw('error');
    });
```

2 - you are subscribing to the observable sequence before the catch method is assigned, therefore the catch method would never run.

So if you add the catch method to your observable sequence and call the subscribe method after the catch method is assigned you will have something like

```
let res = this.serviceApi.getInfo()
    .catch(err => {
        return Observable.throw('error');
    });

res.subscribe(
    res => {
        // success callback
    },
    err => {
        // error callback, err is the error returned from your catch method
    });
```